# Found the expression 目が命 in a paperback I'm reading

Tags: translation, words

... and I don't know what it means. Searching for the term, I've found things like 「戦士は目が命」, which seems to be related to the game Dragon Quest, and 【Firefly Shop】人形は目が命！, on an Amazon product, that follow the same structure as what I'm looking for.

Comment: You didn't mark a best answer for 3 questions that were all answered. It's important that you mark these for future readers of your questions.

Answer (score 4):

This is a way of saying "X is most important".
For example:

> 戦士は目が命
>
> 投手は肩が命

I don't think it's very common but it's a nice way of saying that X is invaluable for Y.

Check this out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sch9SXBaD7k

She says:

> 「芸能人は歯が命」

Comment: この質問を見て最初に思い出したのは「芸能人は歯が命」のCMでしたw

Comment: この表現のどこが"poetic"なんでしょうか？

Comment: I said "poetic" in a slightly tongue-in-cheek style. I'll edit it out since maybe it'll throw people off
.